# AsyncTask's doInBackground returns value before method inside is finished

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, android-asynctask, firebase-authentication

I have created a `AsyncTask` for handling the Sing in. The issue is that Firebase method `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is completed after the `doInBackground` has returned value. I wan't my `onPostExecute(Boolean task)` to respond to whether the login task was successful, but when I check the log messages i can see that `onPostExecute()` finishes before `onComplete()`.
How can i make my `onPostExecute()` after the `onComplete()` and `doInBackground()` have finished.

The Log messages:

```
01-07 12:25:43.775 4046-4241/mk.capitalria.jusufi.riaposdeveloper V/SignInActivity: doInBackground() return type is false
01-07 12:25:43.785 4046-4046/mk.capitalria.jusufi.riaposdeveloper V/SignInActivity: onPostExecute() task is false
01-07 12:25:44.965 4046-4046/mk.capitalria.jusufi.riaposdeveloper V/SignInActivity: onComplete task is successful: true
01-07 12:25:44.965 4046-4046/mk.capitalria.jusufi.riaposdeveloper V/SignInActivity: onComplete task is complete: true
```

The AsyncTask class:

```
 public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        boolean isSuccessful;
        boolean isComplete;
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            signInLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sinInTask.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

            final String email = strings[0];
            final String password = strings[1];

            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).
                    addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            isSuccessful = task.isSuccessful();
                            isComplete = task.isComplete();
                            Log.v(TAG, "onComplete task is successful: " + isSuccessful);
                            Log.v(TAG, "onComplete task is complete: " + isComplete);
                        }
                    });

            Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() return type is " + (isSuccessful && isComplete));
            return isComplete && isSuccessful;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean task) {
            super.onPostExecute(task);
                            Log.v(TAG, "onPostExcecute task is: " + task);

            if (!task) {
                sinInTask.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                signInLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said, you really don't need to use AsyncTask here cause `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()` is non-blocking method. It means that your code is executed not step-by-step but in 2 different `Thread`s. That's why you getting `onPostExecute` first and after when response from `Firebase` comes it prints `onComplete` to logs.

If you really want to use `AsyncTask` you have to wait while `signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns some value and it can be done in following way.

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    boolean isSuccessful;
    boolean isComplete;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    final ReentrantLock loginLock = new ReentrantLock();

    ...

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ...
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        isSuccessful = task.isSuccessful();
                        isComplete = task.isComplete();
                        Log.v(TAG, "onComplete task is successful: " + isSuccessful);
                        Log.v(TAG, "onComplete task is complete: " + isComplete);
                        loginLock.unlock()
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                        loginLock.unlock();
                    }
                });
        loginLock.lock();

        Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() return type is " + (isSuccessful && isComplete));
        return isComplete && isSuccessful;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use AsyncTask here. Firebase performs signInWithEmailAndPassword asynchronously. It calls onComplete when the operation ends so all the code from onPostExecute can be moved to onComplete.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()` is already asynchronous, there is no need to wrap it in an `AsyncTask`.  Rather than perform your actions in `onPostExecute`, do them in your `onComplete` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean task) {
            super.onPostExecute(task);
                            Log.v(TAG, "onPostExcecute task is: " + task);
 firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).
                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        isSuccessful = task.isSuccessful();
                        isComplete = task.isComplete();
                        Log.v(TAG, "onComplete task is successful: " + isSuccessful);
                        Log.v(TAG, "onComplete task is complete: " + isComplete);
                    task=isComplete && isSuccessful;
                    if (!task) {
                    sinInTask.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    signInLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                    }
                });

        }
```

Add `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` to `onPostExecute` because in doInBackground method control won't wait for `onComplete` to be called. so if you want `onPost` code to be execute after onComplete response on some condition basis change your `onPost` like above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AsyncTask here. Firebase's createUserWithEmailAndPassword already works asynchronously. You can perform all your actions in the onComplete function of OnCompleteListener. Here is the code you can use for onComplete and remove the AsyncTask.

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        sinInTask.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        signInLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```